# Google maps doesn't load on Contact page, after moving local site to live. However, it worked fine on localhost

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, localhost

I have moved wordpress site from localhost to godaddy. Every page is working fine apart from the contact page. The google map container does not load, does not show anything, it is completely blank. It worked completely fine in localhost.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Google Developer Page where you created the API key and find the option “Accept requests from these HTTP referrers (web sites)”. Next,  you should add your website URL like this `example.com/*`. After doing so, the map will certainly show. I had the same issue in the past.

Comment: Actually this wordpress site is created by someone else, and they gave me the files, I have not created API for this. Is there any other way? Because the map worked on free hosting service, but not on Godaddy.

Comment: You can create your own API key and replace the old one.

Comment: I created my API key, but I would need more help on how to replace the old one with this one? Is it in database?